# Why doesn't Eclipse CDT Indexer index the right configuration?

Tags: arm, eclipse-cdt, static-analysis, indexer, ds-5

Using Eclipse CDT from a recent ARM Development Studio (DS) release (v2019.a_1), I imported my project settings from a previous installation (DS-5 v5.26.2). The project is comprised of several configurations, intended for various chips in one chip family. Differences are mostly some of the include paths and some of the macro symbols. The configurations are named as the chip numbers, say `XYZ001` to `XYZ007`.

In the code tree, there are directories that are specific to a single chip, and hence should only be included in a specific configuration. Thus, for each configuration, the paths list contain the variant of the relevant chip, e.g., `Core/XYZ003/Include/regs.h`.

Additionally, in the `Project Explorer` view, I am excluding the directories and files from the configurations they do not belong to.

This used to work just fine for a long time, until I updated my DS installation to the 2019 version. Now, there is a specific configuration, `XYZ002`, that is treated as if it was `XYZ007`. The included and excluded resources match the wrong configuration, and as a result, I get multiple error indications in the editor view, of symbols that cannot be resolved. Also, when using the `F2` or `F3` keys, the environment cannot find the definitions of the selected symbols.

There is an option to generate an Indexer parser log file, which I used, and at the beginning of the file, I see:

```
Build Configuration:   XYZ007
```

and not the expected:

```
Build Configuration:   XYZ002
```

I tried switching configurations back-and-forth and rebuilding the index many times. Also tried renaming the problematic configuration, and creating a new one based on that configuration, but this did not help.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time playing around with the IDE, I found the source of the problem. In the global Indexer preferences page (`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Indexer`), one should select `Use active build configuration` rather than `Use the build configuration specified in the project's indexer settings`

[image]